# Follow the reward

Tags: visual

**Something is hidden below. Tell me... what am I saying?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The message here is:

> **CHECKMARK'S YOURS!**

To find this...

> ...add a checkmark in every box:
>
>  [image: Checkmarks in each box]
>
>  Read off the letters each touches, to get C-H-E from the first box, C-K-M from the second, then A-R-K, 'S-Y-O and U-R-S. Altogether, this spells **CHECKMARK'S YOURS** (note the apostrophe seen before the 'S' in the fourth box).
>
>  (The prompt to think in this direction is to note the colour used in the image (green) and 'follow the reward' as per the title - the reward for a correct answer on PSE naturally being a green checkmark!)

Thank you very much!

Comment: That was insanely fast! :)

Comment: @Alaiko Ha, yes - was fortunate to see it pretty much the moment it was posted, and then to have the realisation as to what was expected based off 'reward' and the colour used. The first box's letters then made me realise I had found the right track immediately...!

Comment: Very fast indeed! Good job :)